# How can I dilate a binary image without closing holes with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

How can I apply dilation to the binary image on the left without closing the hole in the loop? I'm also interested in doing it efficiently.

[image]

**Context**: I need to train a CNN to read handwritten digits. Believe it or not, the image on the left is supposed to be a 9. Since the dataset has a lot of 9s written that way I may have a chance at training a model to recognise it. I do need to apply some dilation though, in order to get the digit thickness to be similar to that of the digits fed into the pre-trained model. I think if I lose the hole in the loop, I'll have no chance.

Comment: Why do you think dilating the horribly hand-written 9 is the best solution?

Comment: It's not about the 9 itself. I need to dilate all of the digits. I used the MNIST handwritten digit dataset to pre-train a model. In order for that model to recognise these new digits, I'll need to make them look as similar to the MNIST dataset as possible. I use dilation to match the digit thickness.

Comment: That's not a 9. It's a 4 :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist haha, well I was confused at first but while annotating 3000 of these myself I found out it was a 9 by process of exclusion. Turns out lots of South Koreans write 9s with a little backwards loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to fill the hole inside the contour, inverse it, then multiply it to the dilated image:
[image]

Here is the opencv code (c++):

```
Mat img__ = imread("E:/1.jpg", 0);
Mat img1;

threshold(img__, img1, 0, 255, THRESH_OTSU); # you don't need this line, I used it because I read the image from my hard disk. You can comment this line

vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector< Vec4i > hierarchy;

findContours(img1, contours, hierarchy, RETR_CCOMP, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

Mat tmp = Mat::zeros(img1.size(), CV_8U);

for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    if (hierarchy[i][2] < 0) # this stands for the inner contours which surrounds the hole
        drawContours(tmp, contours, i, Scalar(255, 255, 255), -1);
}
Mat img2;
dilate(img1, img2, Mat::ones(9, 9, CV_8U));

imshow("original", img1);
imshow("1", tmp);
imshow("3", img2);

tmp = 255 - tmp;

imshow("2", tmp);

tmp = tmp / 255;

multiply(tmp, img2, img2);

imshow("4", img2);

waitKey(0);
```