# What are the ways I can use an image set of different dimensions as input to a pretrained model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a handwritten digit recognition problem, using OpenCV for preprocessing and Keras/Tensorflow for inference. I trained a model on the MNIST handwritten digit dataset, where each image is 28x28 pixels. Now I'm working with a new set of digits and I plan to do further training with the original model architecture and transfer learning via weight initialisation.

**So here's my problem**: I'm having an issue with losing certain features when I downsize to 28x28 pixels. Here's an example

[image]

That's meant to be a two, and the tiny gap in the top loop is important in helping differentiate it from a 9 or an 8. But my preprocessed version loses the gap, so the loop looks closed.

I have posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59840210/preserving-connectedness-of-lines-in-an-image-with-opencv) about how to do the downsizing without losing the features. On the other hand, maybe I'd like to downsize to a **larger size like 56x56 pixels** where I'm less likely to lose such features. **How can I set things up such that this new size blends in with the model without rendering the pre-trained weights useless?**

Here is the definition of the pre-trained model:

```
def define_model(learning_rate, momentum):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer = 'he_uniform'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    opt = SGD(lr=learning_rate, momentum=momentum)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Here's one idea I had: Increase the size of the max-pool kernel after the first layer such that the output of that layer has the same shape as if I used 28x28 pixel images. (but won't that cause me to lose the feature anyway?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you upscale the MNST for training? Your question is about the resolution of the image, the MNST dataset was created long ago when GPU memories were still very small. Recent models all have image dimensions bigger than `200 * 200`, for example, resnet uses `224*224` as input shape. Since your image is already low resolution from the beginning, and you downscale and you will make the model hard to differentiate each other. Since your model is fairly simple, I would suggest to upscale the training dataset.

And yes, if you use pooling you mentioned, you probably loose information also.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh great, thanks it was helpful! Do you know of any datasets that have an original size of larger than 28x28? The reason I ask is that it would be nice to capture the original features of the MNIST dataset when pre-training.

Comment: @AlexanderSoare, original one is here, http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/. And you can also email to the author, they might have the original one somewhere, but highly doubt they will response to you. Also check https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/03/comprehensive-collection-deep-learning-datasets/ for insight. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be as suggested above - upscale initial dataset from `28x28` to `56x56` for example.

Second option is adding an additional `MaxPooling` or `AveragePooling` layer in the beginning of your trained model, for example:

```
new_input = Input(shape=(56, 56, 1), name='new_input')
x = AveragePooling2D((2,2), name='avg_pool')(new_input)
new_output = trained_model(x)
new_model = Model(new_input, new_output)
```

Here is a summary of new model:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
new_input (InputLayer)       (None, 56, 56, 1)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
avg_pool (AveragePooling2D)  (None, 28, 28, 1)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
trained_model (Sequential)   (None, 10)                159254    
=================================================================
Total params: 159,254
Trainable params: 159,254
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Thanks. Although if I add this pool layer in I suppose I'll just lose the features I'm interested in anyway right?

Comment: In order not to lose the areas of the image you are interested in (the features) you can use AveragePooling or MinPooling instead of MaxPooling (these all are just ways of downscaling the initial image). Although this is not guaranteed, but I think it's worth to try.